# Node.js Getting error in error in child_process.spawn

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn

i node.js (v10.15.3) I am trying to use psexec which is an exe in pstools. From node.js, I want to execute commands on remote windows server; hence using psexec.exe.

Here is the code i am using,

```
const child_process = require('child_process');  
var lineBuffer = "";

var workerProcess = child_process.spawn('cmd', ['/c', 'PsExec \\\\XXX.XXX.XX.XXX -u username -p password typeperf "\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time"']);

    workerProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) { 
        lineBuffer += data.toString();

        console.log('lineBuffer: ' + lineBuffer);  
    });  
    workerProcess.stderr.on('data', function (data) {  
        console.log('stderr: ' + data);  
    });  
    workerProcess.on('close', function (code) {  
        console.log('process exited with code ' + code);  
    });
```

But this code is giving error,

```
PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com



Starting typeperf on XXX.XXX.XX.XXX...XXX.XX.XXX...
typeperf exited on XXX.XXX.XX.XXX with error code -268435454.

process exited with code 4026531842
```

But when i change command

```
'PsExec \\\\XXX.XXX.XX.XXX -u username -p password typeperf "\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time"'
```

to

```
'PsExec \\\\XXX.XXX.XX.XXX -u username -p password netstat -ano'
```

This does not give error but shows truncated output on console.

```
PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
```

Please suggest something or help to resolve this issue. I am fine if spawn is changed to exec. I have been struggling to fix this for weeks. Many thanks in advance.